# Editing the model object with update view django by excluding fields

Tags: python, django, view, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to `Edit/Update` a model object(record) using django `Updateview`

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from myapp.models import Author

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    description = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
class BookEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Book
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    exclude = ('author',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("books:list_of_books")
```

**books_update_from.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_title %}Edit Book{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
     {{form.as_p}}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When the form is rendered, the `Author` foreign field is still displaying on the page even though i had mentioned it in `exclude` in `BookEditview` as  above

So how to hide that field and submit the form ?

Also i tried by rendering individual fields like `form.book_name`, `form.amount` etc.,(I know this approach does n't solve the above issue but just given a foolish try). when i submit the form, its action is negligable and does nothing because we are not submitting the `author foreign key value` and hence the form is invalid and submit does n't do anything

So what i want to know is how to exclude the field from the model when rendering it as a form using `UpdateView` to edit the model(Am i done something wrong above in my code ?)

Also i want know the concept of `Updateview` that if we exclude the `foreignKey` field then there is no need to submit the foreign Key value ?(Because the Edit form will be valid only if every field including the `Author Foreign Key` is submitted with value ? )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define a BookForm that excludes the field,

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ('author',)
```

then use this form in your view

```
class BookEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
    ...
```

Comment: :Thanks for replying, k is there any way to submit the foreign key value when we click on submit ? i mean can we  override this behavior in form_data or some methods ?

Comment: If you want to change the author you could override the `form_valid` method. See [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) from the docs. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean - why do you want to submit the value when you have deliberately excluded it from the form?

Comment: sorry what i mean is in the case that if we have not written a form class for this. Anyway i got solution from the above answer, but want to further more like if we have not created a  form class ? how to exclude the foreign field because exclude is not working in Updateview

Comment: There is no `exclude` option for `UpdateView`. Creating a custom form is the correct approach.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to style this newly created form? How can I style individual fields and labels of the form in the template?