# Select all fields except one Django

Tags: django

There is a class-based view and I want to know how I can use all fields except the `user` field in the `fields` instead of `'__all__'` and also I don't want to write all the fields in a list because there are too many fields and I want to exclude one item.

here is the code:

```
class TaskCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = '__all__' # ! here
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Tasks')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(TaskCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to define a ModelForm and assign it as form_class attribute to TaskCreate then exclude the field in that ModelForm.

For example: [Here is an exclude example for Update view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918184/editing-the-model-object-with-update-view-django-by-excluding-fields)